# Help with index on database

Tags: database, indexing

Is it a good idea to create an index on a field which is VARCHAR (500) ? I am going to do a lot of search in it, but I am not sure if creating an index on such a 'big' field is a good idea?

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually not a good idea since the index files will be huge and the search relatively slow. It is better to use a prefix of the field such as the first 32 or 64 characters of the field as an index. Another possibility is that if it makes sense use a full text index,.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a good idea to create indexes on fields that you'll use for search. But, depending on the use, there are better options:

- Full text search (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search)): In a full text search, the search engine examines all of the words in every stored document as it tries to match search words supplied by the user.
- Partial index: (again, from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index)): In databases, a partial index, also known as filtered index is an index which has some condition applied to it so that it includes a subset of rows in the table.

Maybe you should consider giving more information on the use that index will have.

Answer (score 0):

You should put indexes where often used queries will run faster, however, there are a number of issues to contemplate

- Indexes have a very limited size, eg. mssql has a 900 byte limit
- Many index may incur an overhead while writing (although minimal last time i benchmarked inserting a million entries on a table with 9 indexes
- Many indexes takes up precious space in the db
- many indexes may create deadlocks when inserting data

Also take a look at the documentation for the database you use. Most databases has support for text columns with efficient searching in them